# Text over arrow using the mathabx package

Tags: macros, mathabx, xrightarrow

I switched to the `mathabx` package and now the command `\xrightarrow` does not work anymore. What's the way to have text over arrows in `mathabx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\xrightarrow` command is defined by `amsmath` and `mathabx` doesn't provide it.

Remember to load `amsmath` before `mathabx`, because the latter needs to override some commands of the former.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

$a\xrightarrow{xyz}b$

\end{document}
```

[image]